# How can I move a directory onto an existing directory?

Tags: rename, synchronization, recursive

I need to essentially merge changes on two trees, applying the changes from branch 2 to branch 1. I have trees like this:

```
media
├── cd
│   ├── 0
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   ├── file2
│   │   └── file3
│   ├── 1
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   ├── file2
│   │   └── file3
│   └── 2
│       ├── file1
│       ├── file2
│       └── file3
├── dvd
│   ├── 0
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   ├── file2
│   │   └── file3
│   ├── 1
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   ├── file2
│   │   └── file3
│   └── 2
│       ├── file1
│       ├── file2
│       └── file3
└── stuff
    ├── 0
    │   ├── file1
    │   ├── file2
    │   └── file3
    ├── 1
    │   ├── file1
    │   ├── file2
    │   └── file3
    └── 2
        ├── file1
        ├── file2
        └── file3
```

I've changed the files in my branch 2, and I need to apply them to branch 1. If I just try moving them over branch 1, I get the following errors:

```
mv: cannot move `/branch2/media/cd' to `/branch1/media/cd': Directory not empty.
```

Is there another command I should be using for this? `mv -f` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Can you post the command that you are using?

Comment: simple `mv /branch2/media/* /branch1/media/`

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but doesn't `mv branch2/media/ branch1/media` work?

Comment: No, as noted below, `mv` won't overwrite files in existing subdirectories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use `rsync` instead?

```
rsync -a /branch2/media/ /branch1/media/
```

The reason why `mv` can't move `/branch2/media/cd/` to `/branch1/media` is because `/branch1/media` already has a `cd/` in it.  `mv` refuses to clobber non-empty directories.

Comment: That looks like it'll work, I ended up using something like this: `yes | cp -af /branch2/media/* /branch1/media`.

Answer (score 3):

You would generally prefer using `rsync` or any other versioning tool.

If you still want to hack, you could start by removing the existing files in /branch1/media/ with `find`

```
find /branch1/media -type d -exec rm -rf {} \+
```

You then proceed to your move

```
for i in $(find /branch2/media -type d); do
    mv /branch2/media/$dir /branch1/media
done
```

You should probably tweak those commands a bit according to your environment, but no reason it wouldn't work.

PS be careful with the `find -exec rm -rf` call. I usually start by checking my find command with `ls` before using `rm`